# Vue-Variables as <option data> Property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

For some reason i have to put the object as json to a Tag Property.
Any Ides how to do this? All examples doesn't work for me.

```
 <html>
 <!---example 1---->
 <option v-for="(book,bookNr) in books"  data-data="{{{book}}}" >
                        {{bookNr}}
                    </option>

 <!---example 2---->
 <option v-for="(book,bookNr) in books" :data-data="'{'+book+'}'" >
                        {{bookNr}}
                    </option>
   <!---example 3---->
   <option v-for="(book,bookNr) in books" :data-data='{"+JSON.stringify(book)+"}"' >
                        {{bookNr}}
                    </option>

  </html>
```

need somethink like:

```
<option data-data='{"type":"repo","username":"selectize"}'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      books: [{type:"repo", username:"selectize2"}, {type:"repo", username:"selectize"}, {type:"repo", username:"selectize3"}]
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
   <div v-for="(book,bookNr) in books" :data-data='JSON.stringify(book)' >
        {{bookNr}}
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, but your example doesn't work for vue3 only for vue2: https://jsfiddle.net/5exjnpm0/ 

Comment: @dazzafact hey mate, why not, check now pls, i updated to vue3

Comment: ok it works: https://jsfiddle.net/5exjnpm0/5/ , but for some reason not in my Script

Comment: if you mean jsfiddle.net/5exjnpm0/5, you can see `data-data='{"type":"repo","username":"selectize"}'` in dev tools there also

Comment: OK, got it all work